# Number of simple subgroups of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I have to find the number of simple subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, with $p$ being prime.

Since the group is Abelian, only subgroups of prime order is simple. The order of the group being $p^3$, then the number of simple subgroups should be the number of subgroups of order $p$, which I guess is 3. Am I right or missing something?

Comment: I think you are correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the only simple subgroups are those of order $p$. But, there are more than $3$ of them.

To generate a subgroup of order $p$, we pick an element of order $p$: There are $p^3 - 1$ of them. However, each subgroup of order $p$ contains $p - 1$ elements of order $p$, and each of those elements generate the same subgroup.

Thus, our initial estimate of $p^3 - 1$ subgroups of order $p$ overcounts by a factor of $p - 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand your general argument. But for the specific group at hand: $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, number of subgroups of order $p$ is 3 so the answer is 3 right?

Comment: No, there are more than 3. You have, at least, the three subgroups generated by $(1, 0, 0),\, (0, 1, 0)$, and $(0, 0, 1)$, right? So that's three. But what about the subgroup generated by $(1, 1, 0)$? It doesn't belong to any of them, so there's at least one more.

Comment: Yep, you're right, missed that and now see your reasoning. Thanks!